# How to Extract the Three First Letters of Current Month in French without Accented Characters?

Tags: strings, french, date, datetime2

Is there a way to extract the 3 first letters of the current month in **French** but WITHOUT acented characters AND with the first letter capitalized - e.g. `Fev` for `Février` (February in english) - AND with 2 exceptions: `Juillet = Jul` and `Juin = Jun` (the third letter in the abbreviation correspond in reality to the fourth letter of the month for these 2 exceptions)?

So, for all 12 month I would like to obtain the following results: `Jan`,`Fev`,`Mar`,`Avr`,`Mai`,`Jun`,`Jul`,`Aou`,`Sep`,`Oct`,`Nov`,`Dec`.

It would be nice to have something like a `\currentMonthAbbreviated` command wich directly output the corresponding abreviation to the current month.

Is there a way to do it with `datetime2` package or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `datetime2` package provides `\DTMfrenchshortMonthname`, but defines it by

```
\newcommand*{\DTMfrenchMonthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1
  \or
  Janvier%
  \or
  F\protect\'evrier%
  \or
  Mars%
  \or
  Avril%
  \or
  Mai%
  \or
  Juin%
  \or
  Juillet%
  \or
  Ao\protect\^ut%
  \or
  Septembre%
  \or
  Octobre%
  \or
  Novembre%
  \or
  D\protect\'ecembre%
  \fi
}
```

and what you have to do is to redefine it according to your wish:

```
\renewcommand*{\DTMfrenchshortMonthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\or
  Jan\or Fev\or Mar\or Avr\or Mai\or Jun\or
  Jul\or Aou\or Sep\or Oct\or Nov\or Dec\fi
}
```

On the other hand this can be completely independent of `datetime2`. You can define your own command

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\shortfrenchmonth}{m}
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {1}{Jan}{2}{Fev}{3}{Mar}{4}{Avr}{5}{Mai}{6}{Jun}
    {7}{Jul}{8}{Aou}{9}{Sep}{10}{Oct}{11}{Nov}{12}{Dec}
   }
   {BAD MONTH NUMBER}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\shortfrenchmonth}{m}
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {1}{Jan}{2}{Fev}{3}{Mar}{4}{Avr}{5}{Mai}{6}{Jun}
    {7}{Jul}{8}{Aou}{9}{Sep}{10}{Oct}{11}{Nov}{12}{Dec}
   }
   {BAD MONTH NUMBER}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\shortfrenchmonth{\month}

\shortfrenchmonth{7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! BTW, I guess it's ``\`` **`re`** `newcommand*{\DTMfrenchshortMonthname}` and not just `\newco[..]` ;-)

Comment: @SylvainRigal Yes, of course!

Answer (score 6):

Brute force:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\frabbmonth}{\ifcase\month What?\or
    Jan\or Fev\or Mar\or Avr\or Mai\or Jun\or Jul\or
    Aou\or Sep\or Oct\or Nov\or Dec\else What?\fi}

\begin{document}

\frabbmonth

\end{document}
```

Explanation: `\month` contains the current month number in the range 1...12. So the `\ifcase` will select the correct abbreviation for the existing months, and give out "What?" if the number is out of range.